# Print a DIV tag in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I wanna print a div in a webpage. How to print a div tag in a web page. [image]

I've attached an image to show what i wanna do. How do i print that **printMe** div, **without printing others.**

Comment: I mean, i wanna take a printout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this in css:

```
@media print {
    *:not(#printMe){
       display:none;
    }
}
```

`*:not(#printMe)` means all except `#printMe` div

If you want to trigger the print in javascript, do `window.print()`

Answer (score 0):

```
function printDiv() {
    var divContents = document.getElementById("mymodelid").innerHTML;
    var a = window.open('', '', 'height=600, width=700');
    a.document.write('<html>');
    a.document.write(divContents);
    a.document.write('</body></html>');
    a.document.close();
    a.print();
}
```